# System.invalidoperationexception sequence contains no elements Web Scraper

Tags: c#, web-scraping, scrapysharp

I'm trying to create a Web Scraper with ScrapySharp. I encountered the following error -

> System.invalidoperationexception sequence contains no elements

Code -

Scraper class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load("https://coronavirus.gob.mx/datos/");

            var nones = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("div#resOrH").ToList();

          
            String confirmados = nones.CssSelect("#gsPosDIV").Single().InnerHtml;


            //String confirmados = nones.CssSelect("div#gsActDIV").FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
            /*I'm try with another method but shows another error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object 
              reference not set to an instance of an object.'
              System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returned null.*/


            Console.WriteLine(confirmados);


        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 p-2" id="resOrH">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Resumen Positivos -->
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-2 noHREF hCard" onclick="$('#sPatType').selectpicker('val', 'Confirmados'); reUpdate();">
                <div class="card border-left-danger shadow">
                    <div class="card-body pl-2 py-2" style="overflow:hidden;">
                        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center" style="min-width:113px;">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-danger text-uppercase mb-1  text-nowrap">Confirmados</div>
                                <div id="gsPosDIV" class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">434,193</div><a class="text-uxs">acumulados</a>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                        <i style="font-size: 20px;" class="fas fa-plus-circle text-gray-400"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I use the Id because page has different divs with the same class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'String confirmados = nones.CssSelect("div#gsPosDIV").Single().InnerHtml;' ?